# performance issue for updating mongo documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collections with about 4M records, 2 of my document fields of this collection are date as string, and I need to change them to ISODate, so arote this small script to do that:

```
db.vendors.find().forEach(function(el){
    el.lastEdited = new Date(el.lastEdited);
    el.creationDate = new Date(el.creationDate)
    db.vendors.save(el)
})
```

but it takes foreverrrr...and I added indexes to those fields, can't I do this in some other way which will be reasonable time to complete?

Comment: Indexes won't matter - you're iterating through all 4 million documents, and not filtering at all. If anything, indexes might *add* to the time, if you have those two properties indexed (since the indexes have to be written as well).

Comment: don't update your db. while using use it as a date

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for the response and for the index explanation. so basically there is no faster way, just have to wait 1-2 hrs for it to finish?

Answer (score 2):

Currently you do a `find` against whole collection which could take a while, also for each `save` call it has to do a network roundtrip from the client (shell) to the server.
EDIT: Removed suggestion to use $match and do this in batches, because `$out` in fact replaces the collection on each run as noted in @Stennie's comment.

(Needless to say, test it in a sample dataset first in a test environment. I haven't tested behavior of new Date() as I don't know your data format)

```
db.vendors.aggregate([

         {
            $project: {
               _id: 1,
               lastEdited: { $add : [new Date('$lastEdited')]},
               creationDate: { $add : [new Date('$creationDate')]},
               field1: 1,
               field2: 1,
               //.. (important to repeat all necessary fields)
            },
         },
         {
            $out: 'vendors',
         },
      ]);
```

Comment: The [`addFields` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) lets you add or replace fields in aggregation without specifying all of the existing fields. Note that using the `$out` operator specifying the source collection as the destination will [replace the existing collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#replace-existing-collection) so this would only be recommendable *without* a  `$match` stage (unless it is OK for non-matching documents to be missing).

Comment: @Stennie, thanks for pointing that out. We also had a similar requirement as the OP (string to int32) and we ended up doing the forEach with save that OP has in their post. Luckily for us our collection was not that large (~200k docs) and it completed in 20 minutes. Is there any other utilities that can do this efficiently?

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific utilities for doing this but I think it would be straightforward to write a script for the shell (or for your favourite driver). Migration requirements between field types are probably going to be bespoke. If you are only updating a few fields I think a more efficient approach would be to iterate the collection with a projection limited to the fields needed for your update. Instead of individual updates sending the whole document over the wire with `save()`, I would queue discrete field updates (using `$set` and `$unset`) as unordered bulk write operations.

Comment: [Bulk write operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) automatically group operations into batches, and unordered bulk write operations are faster than ordered. Drivers automatically group bulk write operations into batches, but if you want more control (for example, varying batch size or [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern)) you could create the batches yourself.